# Using For loop inside function - not returning all values

Tags: php

I am having problems displaying the results of function `calculateGrowth`. As shown below, I would like to find the results for each day of a 10 day period. I used a for loop for obvious reasons. But when I try to display results, all I get back is one result.

```
function calculateGrowth(){
    $days = 0;
    $growth = 10;
    for($days = 0; $days < 10; $days++){
      $totalGrowth = $growth * pow(2, $days/10);
    }
    return $totalGrowth;
}
```

Current Output

```
18.6606598307
```

Desired Output

```
Day Growth
1 - result
. - result
. - result
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$totalGrowth = $growth * pow(2, $days/10);
```

Should be

```
$totalGrowth[] = $growth * pow(2, $days/10);
            ^^
```

So that it becomes an array and contains all the values that you add to it, rather than being a string which gets overwritten on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to get this:

```
function calculateGrowth() {    
    list($days, $growth, $table) = array(range(1, 10), 10, array());

    foreach ($days as $day) {

      $table[$day] = $growth * pow(2, $day/10);
    }

    return $table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct as your final loop is doing this

```
$totalGrowth = 10 * pow(2, 9/10)
$totalGrowth = 10*1.8660659830736;
$totalGrowth = 18.660659830736;
```

Edit : Removed last comment